# Receive HLS stream and rebroadcast

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, http-live-streaming

I have commercial streaming server that streams via HLS in Europe.

`http://europe.server/stream1/index.m3u8`

Now my clients in USA having some network issues due to distance.

So I have deployed new server in USA. I'd like it to receive HLS streams from European server and respond to US based customers.

So users can access like

`http://usa.server/stream1/index.m3u8`

It will be H265/HEVC only so RTMP is not possible. Every tutorial I see on internet is based on RTMP.

I have used following config from https://docs.peer5.com/guides/setting-up-hls-live-streaming-server-using-nginx/ for reference.

```
worker_processes  auto;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    aio on;
    directio 512;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    
    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            # Disable cache
            add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';
            
            # CORS setup
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';
            
            # allow CORS preflight requests
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }   
            
            types {
                application/dash+xml mpd;
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }   
            
            root /mnt/;
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is much easier than it seems.

You don't need anything but a caching proxy server.  All the video work has been already done for you.

An Nginx config file similar to this will be fine:

```
proxy_cache_path /path/to/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=100g 
             inactive=10m use_temp_path=off;

server {
    location / {
        proxy_cache my_cache;
        proxy_pass http://europe.example.com;
    }
}
```

See also:  https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/#proxy_cache

Also, I highly recommend using an existing CDN, which will improve performance and reduce your maintenance costs.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I've used this https://docs.peer5.com/guides/use-nginx-as-wowza-cache/ as basic and updated for my needs. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear, what is the question, but answer is: no, nginx is not good for it.

You still need video streaming server in USA, because if you want to deliver dash + hls, you need to repack video in USA in both containers.

Nginx will send all traffic twice (more than twice), video streamer will send it once.